# Android: Populate Gallery With Images from SDCard

Tags: android, image, file

I'm trying to populate a Gallery view with images from a folder in the SDcard. I read the Gallery tutorial on Android Dev seen here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html, and can get it working with images from the drawable folder of my project.

My question is: how can I get an array of files from the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyPictureDirectory folder, and then display them in the Gallery? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following,

```
File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyPictureDirectory"+File.separator);
File imageList[] = file.listFiles();
for(int i=0;i<imageList.length;i++)
{
   //Add images in Gallery from imageList
}
```

To set image from file path:

```
File imgFile = new  File(imagefilepath);
if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Comment: how do i set file object to imageview?

Comment: i have tried all the methods available but still my gridview lags because of bitmap decoading

Comment: @Siddhesh: Are you getting any error,whats your status Siddhesh?

Comment: no errors... code is running perfectly but just that grid lags because 
    `cr.moveToPosition(position);
    int imageID = cr.getInt(columnIndex);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Integer.toString(imageID) );
String url = uri.toString();
int originalImageId = Integer.parseInt(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length()));
Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),
                             originalImageId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
picturesView.setImageBitmap(b);`

in getView()